# how can i remove all cookies from browser

Tags: javascript, cookies

I can do logout but at that time localhost cookies folder are not clear that's why my site user is not logout properly.

```
<li>
       <button id="btnLogoff" onclick="deleteAllCookies()">LOGOFF / logout</button>
  </li>
 <script>
                            function deleteAllCookies() {
                                var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

                                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                                    var cookie = cookies[i];
                                    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
                                    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
                                    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

Comment: You need to remove session from server side. Only removing cookies from client side will intact your session

Comment: i only remove all cookies from client side . like cart,.AspNet.ApplicationCookie And __RequestVerificationToken this three cookies remove from client side

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error that prevents your javascript method from calling

USe `deleteAllCookies()` instead of `deleteAllCookies`

```
<button id="btnLogoff" onclick="deleteAllCookies()">LOGOFF / logout</button>
```

Comment: it's steel not working

Comment: I created cookie and tried to delete it from your code and its successfully removing it